# Utilizing Foundry APIs, how do you get the number or rows and columns for a dataset?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I'm looking to retrieve the number of records and columns within a dataset utilizing the APIs within Foundry. One of the APIs that I found that seems to display the number of records is
".../monocle/api/table/stats", however I don't see how to pass through the rid for a dataset.

I'm ultimately trying to get the total columns, records and size for all the datasets I manage in order to build a dashboard using Quiver or Slate to show the amount of data we manage within the Foundry platform.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following sample code to calculate statistics for a dataset:

```py
import time
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import json

def calculate_dataset_stats(token: str,
                            dataset_rid: str,
                            branch='master',
                            api_base='https://foundry-stack.com'
                            ) -> dict:
    """
    Calculates statistics for last transaction of a dataset in a branch
    Args:
        dataset_rid: the dataset rid
        branch: branch of the dataset

    Returns: a dictionary with statistics

    """
    start_stats_calculation = requests.post(f"{api_base}/foundry-stats/api/stats/datasets/"
                                            f"{dataset_rid}/branches/{quote_plus(branch)}",
                                            headers={
                                                'content-type': "application/json",
                                                'authorization': f"Bearer {token}",
                                            })
    start_stats_calculation.raise_for_status()
    metadata = start_stats_calculation.json()
    transaction_rid = metadata['view']['endTransactionRid']
    schema_id = metadata['view']['schemaId']

    calculated_finished = False
    maybe_stats = {
        'status': 'FAILED'
    }

    while not calculated_finished:
        response = requests.get(f"{api_base}/foundry-stats/api/stats/datasets/"
                                f"{dataset_rid}/branches/{quote_plus(branch)}",
                                headers={
                                    'content-type': "application/json",
                                    'authorization': f"Bearer {token}",
                                },
                                params={
                                    'endTransactionRid': transaction_rid,
                                    'schemaId': schema_id
                                })
        response.raise_for_status()
        maybe_stats = response.json()
        if (maybe_stats['status'] == 'SUCCEEDED') or (maybe_stats['status'] == 'FAILED'):
            calculated_finished = True
        time.sleep(0.5)

    if maybe_stats['status'] != 'SUCCEEDED':
        raise ValueError(f'Stats Calculation failed for dataset {dataset_rid}. '
                         f'Failure handling not implemented.')

    return maybe_stats['result']['succeededDatasetResult']['stats']


token = "eyJwb..."
dataset_rid = "ri.foundry.main.dataset.14703427-09ab-4c9c-b036-1234b34d150b"
stats = calculate_dataset_stats(token, dataset_rid)

print(json.dumps(stats, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171958#68175385) uses **computeStats** and **getDatasetStats** Foundry APIs. There's another API - **getComputedDatasetStats** - which gets your required stats and may even perform better.

According to my tests:

- getDatasetStats is not available unless computeStats is run. The latter takes time. On the other hand, getComputedDatasetStats is available right away.
- getComputedDatasetStats will return `sizeInBytes`, but only if computeStats is not run. When I called the computeStats API, and it finished the job, `sizeInBytes` became null. getDatasetStats showed null too.

To get the row count, column count and dataset size you may try using something similar to this:

```py
import requests
import json

def getComputedDatasetStats(token, dataset_rid, api_base='https://.....'):
    response = requests.post(
        url=f'{api_base}/foundry-stats/api/computed-stats-v2/get',
        headers={
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        data=json.dumps({
            "datasetRid": dataset_rid,
            "branch": "master"
        })
    )
    return response.json()

token = 'eyJwb.....'
dataset_rid = 'ri.foundry.main.dataset.1d9ef04e-7ec6-456e-8326-1c64b1105431'

result = getComputedDatasetStats(token, dataset_rid)

# full resulting json:
# print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))

# required statistics:
print('size:', result['computedDatasetStats']['sizeInBytes'])
print('rows:', result['computedDatasetStats']['rowCount'])
print('cols:', len(result['computedDatasetStats']['columnStats']))
```

Example output:

```
size: 24
rows: 2
cols: 2
```